# arraylist displays zeros instead of my inputs

Tags: java

i have this problem with my array list and i cant seem to solve it. i made sure that it directly stores into the array list but it still displays zeros instead of what i input. I've asked my friends about it and they don't know either. it keeps displaying zeros instead.

i showed this to my friends and they say nothing is wrong with it but i think there is something wrong with it though.

`import java.util.*;`

`public class ArrayListAgain{`

```
public static void main(){
    ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> divby2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> divby3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> divby5 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int s;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in ); 
    System.out.println("How many integers do you want to enter?" );
    s=scan.nextInt();
    Integer ints;


     for (int i = 0; i < s; i++){             
      ints = new Integer(scan.nextInt());
      integers.add(ints);

      if(ints.getInteger()%2 == 0){
          divby2.add(ints);
        }

      if(ints.getInteger()%3 == 0){
          divby3.add(ints);
        }

      if(ints.getInteger()%5 == 0){
          divby5.add(ints);
        }

      }


         System.out.println("Integers Entered: " );
      for(int a=0; a<integers.size(); a++)
        {
            System.out.print(integers.get(a).getInteger()+ ",");  
            }

         System.out.println("Divisible by 2:");
      for(int a =0; a<divby2.size(); a++){
             System.out.print(divby2.get(a).getInteger()+ ",");  
          }

             System.out.println("Divisible by 3:");
      for(int a =0; a<divby3.size(); a++){

             System.out.print(divby3.get(a).getInteger()+",");

    }

         System.out.println("Divisible by 5:");
         for(int a =0; a<divby5.size(); a++){

             System.out.print(divby5.get(a).getInteger()+",");

    }
  }
}}
```

//*2nd class*//

`public class Integer(){`

`private int Number;`

```
public Integer(int x){  
    this.Number=Number;
}

public void setInteger(){  
    this.Number=Number;
}

public int getInteger(){  
    return Number;
}}
```

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: arrays don't have an .add(x) method. also: have you debugged to check whether or not any of those if statements returns true? This question is about arrays, but you show no array or call on one

Comment: I'm sorry i got a  little excited

Comment: show the whole code

Comment: added the whole code

Comment: You have a type-o: `this.number=number;`

Comment: thanks, that worked but it wont check if the number is divisible by 2,3 or 5 and store them in their respective array list.

Comment: my bad i was still using the old for loop. thanks so much everyone sorry for being a hassle

Answer (score 0):

This is because the constructor of your self-defined Integer class is wrong.
It should be

```
private int number;    
public Integer(int x){
       this.number = x;
}
```

Also, you don't need to define setter if you already have a constructor.

Also, I would advise you to use the java.lang.Integer class instead of defining your own.

Comment: you do know that `Integer` is a default java class with a proper constructor? you can't assume that OP uses a new `Integer` class